# Email button from sqlite database. Confusion over Null Value call

Tags: android, sqlite, email

I am trying to send an email, from a button click, to all emails stored in a sqlite database. I have been successful in selecting one email, but now i am trying to use a cursor to continue to send the email to all stored email addresses. The problem I am having is that i cant figure out where the null value is coming from. I am using code that i have never used before, and am having a little trouble error checking the code itself. Below is the button call and the method to retrieve the array of addresses from the database.

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btn_save).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View view ) { 
          Mail m = new Mail("gmail@gmail.com", "password"); 



          String[] usereMail = getEmailsFromDB().split(",");
          m.setTo(usereMail); 
          m.setFrom("gmail@gmail.com"); 
          m.setSubject("subject"); 
          m.setBody("Body"); 

          try { 

            if(m.send()) { 
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else { 
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
          } catch(Exception e) { 
            //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
          } 
        }

        private String getEmailsFromDB() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dataBase = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor Cursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT " + DbHelper.KEY_EMAIL + " FROM "
                    + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);


            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(Cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String usereMail = Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_EMAIL));
                array.add(usereMail);

            }

            Cursor.close();
            return null;

        } 
      });
```

Below is the NullPointerException that is catching.

```
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at app.norman.tennis.FoursFragment$1.onClick(FoursFragment.java:61)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
03-31 11:30:15.344: E/AndroidRuntime(15802):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is the array of email addresses being created incorrectly or is the email call coded incorrectly, or is it something completely different?

Comment: what is line number 61 in FoursFragment.java

Comment: may be m is null check it.

Comment: I changed the getter and setter for m.setTo. This in turn has created the null value coming line 60 which is String[] usereMail = getEmailsFromDB().split(",");

Comment: then `getEmailsFromDB()` returns null value,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're literally returning null from the method `getEmailsFromDB()`

Check the line `return null;`

Comment: Can you advise as to what return i should use so that the call is done correctly?

Comment: Return the array. `return array;`

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to String

Comment: Change the return type of the method to `ArrayList<String>` and handle the result appropriately from where you're calling it.

Comment: Thankyou Joel. I am having troubles with the split now but you have answered the question correctly :)

Comment: Once i change the method to ArrayList<String> i struggle to handle the result. Is there any way i can get the emails called through using String[]?

Comment: @RunningWalks You can convert the ArrayList to String array. Try this:

`ArrayList<String> list = getEmailsFromDB();
String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`